# HERE Maps - truck restrictions

Tags: here-api

I'm using the Here API to calculate routes for trucks with 40t. Using the HERE devtools, i got the same error of my APP. The answer is "The API can't calculate the route because of illegal access". I checked the map (image attached) and in the street where my journey will start, with a difference of some meters, it exists two limitations 12t and 18t. The street is one way... If you see the satellite image exists several trucks... The company is testing the software says the trucks goes their...
Can some help me on this?

[image]
https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=41.325299,2.141551&waypoint1=stopOver,3600!41.3291843,2.0317197&waypoint2=stopOver,3600!40.91260530,-8.42291420&waypoint3=38.855951,-9.104382&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:enabled&departure=2020-08-19T02:57:58&alternatives=0&weightPerAxle=14t&limitedWeight=40t&height=4m&width=2.55m&length=16.5m&trailersCount=

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore the restrictions for trucks in the route, add the parameter `truckRestrictionPenalty` and set the value to `soft`.

The route violating truck restrictions is indicated in the response with dedicated route and manoeuvre `notes`. The route with the note of the type violation and the text `truckRestriction` may be travelled at your own responsibility. While driving on such a route, extra care has to be taken as it may result in a vehicle or road infrastructure damage.

You can read more about the parameter [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-route.html).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your feedback, but we are using the Fleet Telematics Api not the Routing API. Using your info, We researched a litle more and we found the equivalent parameter: ignoreWaypointVehicleRestriction.

We added these params &ignoreWaypointVehicleRestriction=5000;0;all and the API returned the route with the warning.

Thanks,